# Npm install throws warn old lockfile error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

`npm 8.1.2` | `node 16.13.1`

Npm throws the error below when I use `npm install`, I believe it is about versions but not sure, I installed `npm` version 7.19.1 but still got the same error, any idea why and how to solve this issue?

```
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN deprecated ini@1.3.5: Please update to ini >=1.3.6 to avoid a prototype pollution issue
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.3: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated node-pre-gyp@0.11.0: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped package will recieve updates in the 
future
```

Comment: absolutely, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means that the `package-lock.json` file was created while performing an `npm install` with an `npm` version less than 7.

`npm 7` has changed not only the format of `package-lock.json`, but also how it handles peer dependencies. When you upgrade to a newer `npm` version ( >=7 ) make sure to test everything properly with a freshly checked out repo that still has the old file version.

You can resolve the issue (when all testing went well) by committing and pushing the `package-lock.json` in the new format.

Comment: Can you explain how to do this please?
You can resolve the issue (when all testing went well) by committing and pushing the package-lock.json in the new format.

Comment: It's all explained in the answer already. Switch to npm>=7, run npm install and then commit and push the new package-lock.json.

Comment: I too would like to know the code.